# Adding to end of Vagrant path

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I would like to create a generic dev Vagrant environment that I can `vagrant up` from anywhere on my system. I [know](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/) that Vagrant searches for a `Vagrantfile` starting with CWD, then in each parent directory. I also know that setting the `VAGRANT_CWD` environment variable allows you to tell Vagrant to **start** searching in a given directory.

So, I could do something like this: `export VAGRANT_CWD=~/.dotfiles/vdevbox`, where `vdevbox` contains the `Vagrantfile` and other relevant stuff for my dev environment. This allows me me to `vagrant up` from anywhere, but it takes precedence over Vagrantfiles in my CWD, which makes it impossible to use other Vagrant environments (clearly a fail).

So, basically I need the Vagrant equivalent of Bash's `PATH=$PATH:~/some/path`. Is this supported, or is there a better way of meeting this use-case?

*Edit to address @arturhoo's answer*

The same help page linked above mentions merging settings via a `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`. I *think* that this is a different thing than Vagrant's search of dirs for a Vagrantfile to start an env from. I *think* it's strictly limited to **merging** settings, and Vagrant must **additionally** find a `Vagrantfile` via the search method described above. I tried it, and the results seem to support my hypothesis.

```
[~/.vagrant.d]$ ls -rc | tail -n 2
Vagrantfile
bootstrap.sh
[~/test]$ ls
[~/test]$ vagrant up
# Error message about missing Vagrantfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default `Vagrantfile` for your user under `~/.vagrant.d`. If no Vagrantfile is found in your current dir, it will default to that one.

An alternative and more obstrusive way is defining at Vagrantfile at `/`: `/Vagrantfile`

More info on 'Load Order and Merging' at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ especially this notice:

> At each level, settings set will be merged with previous values. What this exactly means depends on the setting. For most settings, this means that the newer setting overrides the older one. However, for things such as defining networks, the networks are actually appended to each other. By default, you should assume that settings will override each other. If the behavior is different, it will be noted in the relevant documentation section.

Comment: I saw this and tried it. I get the impression that this works for merging settings, but that it's distinct from the search-paths-to-find-a-Vagrantfile-to-load process. Long story short: it doesn't work in practice (or have you seen it work?). I'll add a note in my question.